# libgnutls28-dev: apt is searching for the wrong file?

Tags: linux, apt, gnutls, debian-buster

I am having trouble installing libgnutls28-dev package on debian buster, apt throws the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  gnutls-bin gnutls-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libgnutls28-dev
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,086 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,417 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 libgnutls28-dev amd64 3.6.7-4
  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.220.204 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gnutls28/libgnutls28-dev_3.6.7-4_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 151.101.220.204 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

The thing that bugs me is that the package is available at http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gnutls28/libgnutls28-dev_3.6.7-4+deb10u2_amd64.deb, and for some reason apt is looking for `libgnutls28-dev_3.6.7-4_amd64.deb` instead of `libgnutls28-dev_3.6.7-4+deb10u2_amd64.deb`.

I tried using a specific version running `apt install libgnutls28-dev=3.6.7-4+deb10u2` and got the following:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '3.6.7-4+deb10u2' for 'libgnutls28-dev' was not found
```

The question is where does this come from? is it an `apt` issue? or is it `gnutls28` misinforming about dependencies? or should there be a file `libgnutls28-dev_3.6.7-4_amd64.deb` in the first place?

[EDIT]

Adding this based on Knud's comment:

According to `apt` the system is up-to-date:

```
apt update
```

```
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease            
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease                        
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

I confirmed with one of the package mantainers, the available version `_3.6.7-4+deb10u2` **is** the latest version, and `apt` should be aware of this, yet:

```
apt-cache policy libgnutls28-dev
```

```
libgnutls28-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.6.7-4
  Version table:
     3.6.7-4 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 Packages
```

So this is an `apt` issue. For some reason `apt`, even with supercow powers, is stuck in an outdated state of affairs. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at "available packages" http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gnutls28/ ... No issues here, Debian 10 : `# apt install libgnutls28-dev` ... Not easy to guess why a non existing package is called for. ... May be you can remove libgnutlsxx28 ? And install the new version ?

Comment: Thanks Knud, what version do you get installed? ```3.6.7-4``` or ```3.6.7-4+deb10u2```?

Comment: The latest "Buster version" is always the one to be installed : `3.6.7-4+deb10u2` https://packages.debian.org/buster/libgnutls28-dev ... Could be its'a while since you have updated the package list ? → → `# apt update`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, thanks to kind guidance by Andreas Metzler.

The mirror apparently is stuck with an outdated package index. I was using `deb.debian.org` that as i understand redirects `apt` to a nearby server. I updated the `sources.list` files in `/etc/apt/` so they now point to a fixed nearby server and everything runs ok.